# For each file in a directory in a Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have this project structure:

```
/project
    |
    |____/bin
    |
    |
    |____/obj
    |
    |
    |____/include
    |    |
    |    |____aaa.h
    |    |
    |    |____bbb.h
    |    |
    |    |____ccc.h
    |
    |
    |____/src
    |    |
    |    |____aaa.c
    |    |
    |    |____bbb.c
    |    |
    |    |____ccc.c
    |
    |
    |____/test
    |    |
    |    |____aaa_test.c
    |    |
    |    |____bbb_test.c
    |    |
    |    |____ccc_test.c
    |
    |
    |____Makefile
```

I need to write a Makefile to test every module in this project. For each file in the `test` folder I should compile the relative module (same name without "_test") in `src` folder and create the executable in the folder `bin`.

List of commands to execute:

```
gcc -Wall -g -I include -c src/aaa.c -o obj/aaa.o
gcc -Wall -g -I include -c test/aaa_test.c -o obj/aaa_test.o
gcc obj/aaa.o obj/aaa_test.o -o bin/aaa_test.exe

gcc -Wall -g -I include -c src/bbb.c -o obj/bbb.o
gcc -Wall -g -I include -c test/bbb_test.c -o obj/bbb_test.o
gcc obj/bbb.o obj/bbb_test.o -o bin/bbb_test.exe

gcc -Wall -g -I include -c src/ccc.c -o obj/ccc.o
gcc -Wall -g -I include -c test/ccc_test.c -o obj/ccc_test.o
gcc obj/ccc.o obj/ccc_test.o -o bin/ccc_test.exe
```

My current Makefile:

```
CC := gcc
CCFLAGS := -Wall -g
INC := -I include
BINDIR := bin
OBJDIR := obj
SRCDIR := src
TESTDIR := test

all: $(BINDIR)/aaa_test.exe $(BINDIR)/bbb_test.exe $(BINDIR)/ccc_test.exe

NAME = aaa

$(BINDIR)/$(NAME)_test.exe: $(OBJDIR)/$(NAME).o $(OBJDIR)/$(NAME)_test.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/$(NAME).o: $(SRCDIR)/$(NAME).c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/$(NAME)_test.o: $(TESTDIR)/$(NAME)_test.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

NAME = bbb

$(BINDIR)/$(NAME)_test.exe: $(OBJDIR)/$(NAME).o $(OBJDIR)/$(NAME)_test.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/$(NAME).o: $(SRCDIR)/$(NAME).c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/$(NAME)_test.o: $(TESTDIR)/$(NAME)_test.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

NAME = ccc

$(BINDIR)/$(NAME)_test.exe: $(OBJDIR)/$(NAME).o $(OBJDIR)/$(NAME)_test.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/$(NAME).o: $(SRCDIR)/$(NAME).c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/$(NAME)_test.o: $(TESTDIR)/$(NAME)_test.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@
```

Can I read the name of each file in the `test` folder and optimize my Makefile?

Comment: Do understand simple makefiles? Do you have a working makefile for this project?

Comment: I tried to obtain all object file from `src` and `test` folders and put them in `obj` folder but I can't do it.

Comment: **Do you have a working makefile?** Can you write a makefile that builds `aaa_test.exe`?

Comment: There's a saying that to one who's got a hammer everything looks like nails. You don't have to do the entire task as a makefile; use other scripting or shell languages to generate the test makefiles.

Comment: @Beta I just edited the post and added my current makefile

Comment: It is a mistake to have the include files in a separate directory from the C files.

Comment: @shawnhcorey Why? Where can I found information about a correct folders structure project?

Comment: @giusepped An include file is also a source file. The confusion comes from where libraries are installed. They and their include files were put in separate directories to speed up the compiler in finding them. But this is only for installed libraries, not development source files. It is better to have the *.c and *.h files grouped by functionality; perhaps a sub-directory for each component. Separating files by type rather than functionality makes it harder for those unfamiliar with the project to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @shawnhcorey Initially, *.c and *.h were togheter in `src` and there was a folder for each component. After I read an online guide about folders structure, I edited my structure. But I didn't understand the use of the folder `include`. Now, I return to my orginal structure. Thank you :)

Comment: @giusepped I've been trying to find an answer to your other question about a project's file structure. There is no consensus but most of what I found does not have an `include/` directory. Usually there is is a `src/` directory for the sources and a `build/` one for compiling. Meta-information files, like README, MANIFEST, and LICENCE, are place in the project's root directory so they are easy to find. (And they are capitalized for the same reason.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with having regular source files (`foo.c`), test sources (`foo_test.c`), header files (`foo.h`), object files (`foo.o`) and executables (`foo.exe`) in separate directories, and it's not difficult to write a makefile that will handle it.

Let's start with your current makefile:

```
NAME = aaa

$(BINDIR)/$(NAME)_test.exe: $(OBJDIR)/$(NAME).o $(OBJDIR)/$(NAME)_test.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/$(NAME).o: $(SRCDIR)/$(NAME).c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/$(NAME)_test.o: $(TESTDIR)/$(NAME)_test.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

# repeated for bbb and ccc
```

But instead of copy-and-paste with a `NAME` variable, we'll write these as [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
$(BINDIR)/%_test.exe: $(OBJDIR)/%.o $(OBJDIR)/%_test.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%_test.o: $(TESTDIR)/%_test.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

# no repetition needed
```

And if you want you can combine those last two rules into one, using the [vpath directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search) to tell Make where to search for sources:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@

vpath %.c $(SRCDIR) $(TESTDIR)
```

Now instead of spelling out all of the tests:

```
all: $(BINDIR)/aaa_test.exe $(BINDIR)/bbb_test.exe $(BINDIR)/ccc_test.exe
```

You can have Make look in the test directory with [`wildcard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function):

```
TEST_SOURCES := $(wildcard $(TESTDIR)/*.c)    
TESTS := $(patsubst $(TESTDIR)/%_test.c,$(BINDIR)/%_test.exe,$(TEST_SOURCES))

all: $(TESTS)
```

P.S. You can also use wildcard to find all sources of a module according to your naming convention, like src/aaa_1.c and src/aaa_2.c, but that's another matter and this answer is getting long.

Answer (score 0):

That Makefile looks strange to begin with.  I'd advise you get rid of `$(OBJDIR)` and `$(BINDIR)` so Make can just compile to the current directory, and we can use its built-in rules to save us having to write our own.  And we can use `$(wildcard )` to find the `*_test.c` source files and determine the appropriate targets using `$(patsubst )` like this:

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -g
CFLAGS += -Iinclude
SRCDIR := src
TESTDIR := test

# Source files locations
VPATH = $(SRCDIR):$(TESTDIR)

all-tests: $(patsubst $(TESTDIR)/%.c,%,$(wildcard $(TESTDIR)/*_test.c))

%_test: %_test.o %.o
    $(LINK.c) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

(Note that I changed `CCFLAGS` to `CFLAGS`, so we can just allow the default `%.o: %.c` rule to do its thing).  It's now much shorter and simpler, and lower-maintenance.

Comment: And if I want to save objects file in `obj` and executable in `bin`?

Comment: My recommendation: don't do that.  If you must, then it's better to have the Makefile in `obj` where you want your outputs (and make it move the binaries to `bin`).  But really, just let `Make` build in the current directory, and let your `install` rule deal with copying stuff elsewhere.

Comment: Another question: if I have different .c in `src` related to the same module (for example `src/aaa_1.c` and `src/aaa_2.c`) with the same initial text (in this example `aaa`), how can I edit the above Makefile to compile togheter files of the same module?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it properly using the "Ask" button - a comment isn't the right place.  Thanks.